# How to get this M?

Tags: fonts

I want to get this M in LaTeX:

[image]

I don't get this style using `\mathcal{M}`, `\mathbb{M}` nor `\mathfrak{M}`.

How can I get it?
I don't want to change the font of the whole document, I just want to insert that M with that style.

Comment: [Identifying the font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture) would be a good start.

Comment: After you know what font it is, see: [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document)

Comment: With some font packages also `\mathscr{M}` works.

Comment: As I realized it just now, that this was your first question: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found it by trial & error with a huge portion of luck. This shape of an M is obviously included in the Euler Virtual Fonts (`eulervm`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{M}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of calligraphic M in Euler-VM]

`eulervm` is designed to be loaded with other fonts not containing math characters. So simply load your other font package.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to import the letter you need; you can take it, for example, from Euler Script:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{eus}{\skewchar\font'60}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{eus}{m}{n}{%
     <-6>eusm5%
    <6-8>eusm7%
    <8->eusm10%
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{eus}{b}{n}{%
     <-6>eusb5%
    <6-8>eusb7%
    <8->eusb10%
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{eus}{U}{eus}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Mscr}{2}{eus}{77}

\begin{document}

$\Mscr$

\end{document}
```

[image]